MS Outlook Invitation going to wrong email address
I've recently started having an issue sending to contacts with 2 emails in their contact record  - both in the CLient and Web versions.
I try to send an invite to email address 1, but it insists on sending it to email 2 (even if I type in the full email address 1).  In the Client version only the name appears and no change is possible.  In the Web version it shows as "Email Name" - and I am then able to edit the imported address in the Web version.
When I do edit it in the web version email, however, it does not recogonise the sendee as the original contact, seeing it as a new one.

Is there any connection between these two accounts?
